# Essay Formatting

Tags: formatting

I have an essay I need to write and I would like to use MacTeX, however it has been very challenging to get it formatted to all of my prof.'s requirements.
If someone could help that would be SO helpful as I am still fairly new to LaTeX, but I would like to get better. The formatting needed is below.

**Formatting guidelines:**
Times

12-point font

Double-spaced

Put name and date in single space at top of page

Put last name and page # in header section of following pages

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) so we can see what you've got so far. This makes it easier for people to help and shows you have made an effort yourself. Also, please confirm that using LaTeX is not itself part of the assignment.

Comment: Searching yields much information.  12pt font: p.21 (section 2.2.2) of the LaTeX User Guide, by L. Lamport; Spacing: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/819/double-line-spacing; custom page headers: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87789/page-numbers-and-headers; and name & date is as easy as typing "Jahrme Risner, 11 September 2014" as the first thing in your document.

Answer (score 11):

I think this does what you require.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}     % Enhanced control over headers and footers 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  % Font encoding
\usepackage{mathptmx}     % Choose Times font 
\usepackage{microtype}    % Improves line breaks      
\usepackage{setspace}     % Makes the document look like horse manure 
\usepackage{lipsum}       % For dummy text

\pagestyle{fancy} % Default page style 
\lhead{My name}
\chead{}
\rhead{\thepage}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

\thispagestyle{empty} %First page style 

\setlength\headheight{15pt} %Slight increase to header size

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\textbf{My Name} \\
\textbf{\today}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\doublespacing

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: *horse manure* :)

Comment: You may want to move the horse-manure comment to the line that says `\doublespacing`... (The `setspace` package, per se, isn't horse manure, right?)

Comment: `horse manure` -- best code comment line ever.